# Shading Render Not Present In 3D View

Tags: rendering, shadows

back again with my sword :D

I've figured out rendering and everything thanks to you guys but this time I'm asking about why there seems to be a shadow that I don't think should be present when looking through the Solid viewport. I'll show the difference with pictures in rendered view and solid. Keep in mind moving the lamps in the scene didn't change anything. Rendered:

[image]

[image]

Solid^

Comment: Ths could have many causes. Please [attach your blend file](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/630/announcing-blend-exchange-a-new-solution-to-blend-hosting). It could be face/vertex normals, duplicate faces, or any strange lighting setup. Really hard to diagnose from these images.

Comment: Looks like a subdivision surface changed it... Unfortunately I'm stupid and changed things around a little and didn't make a new save file. I can still show you the new version but I don't think it has the issue, at least not what I can see. However I would like to ask you if there's an easy way to get rid of duplicate faces like there is with vertices as I seem to have a bad habit of making faces that overlap and stuff like that...

Comment: Getting rid of duplicate vertices/faces can be done by selecting the wanted vertices and then using Mesh > Vertices > Remove Doubles (or Ctrl+V > Remove Doubles, or Tools > Remove Doubles, there are plenty of ways)